# Using function pointer with class or function in php

Tags: php, function, class, pointers

I am converting an old project that uses all functions to use a class. Not all installed instances will be updated so I have to have the code work with the function or the class but I can't get it to work. Here is an outline of the code I am using:

```
    function GetStatus($id) {
       return true;
    }

    class myclass (
       public function GetStatus($id) {
          return true;
       }
    }

    if (class_exists('myclass')) {
       $fcn = $myclass->GetStatus;
    } else {  
       $fcn = GetStatus;
    } 

    echo 'result = ' . $fcn($user_id);
```

So the code checks if the class exists and uses that method, else it uses the function. The code runs without errors but when the class method is used the return is not shown. That is, the results are

```
    result = 1   //when function is used
    result =     //when method is used
```

Is this possible? If it matters, the minimum php version is 7.1.

Comment: The code in your question contains a couple of syntax errors. Please correct them and then check whether what you allege in your question is still true. Simply trying to run the code will show you all the errors.

Comment: It's not meant to be usable code. I was trying to get the concept explained. As mentioned, the actual code runs without errors - just not the correct output.

Comment: I corrected all the errors in your code, as best as I could, ran that code, and I cannot reproduce the problem you report. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the value of `$myclass`?

Comment: @Barmar $myclass is an instance of that class. My code doesn't show the creation since I I thought it was implied by the name.

Comment: When asking why something isn't working the way you think it should, it's best to post the exact code instead of partial or pseudocode so that we can test it out and see the exact flow of the code.

Comment: `$myclass->GetStatus` is used to access a property, not a method. To get a callable, you use `[$myclass, 'GetStatus']`

Comment: My apologies for not posting a better example. I will try to do better in future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a callable from an instance and method, you use an array containing the instance and the method name.

```
       $fcn = [$myclass, 'GetStatus'];
```

Comment: Well, if you're going to answer this question, then you could also add that, to make a "callable" from a function, it should be: `$fcn = 'GetStatus';`. 

Comment: A nice short version: `$fcn = class_exists('myclass') ? [$myclass, 'GetStatus'] : 'GetStatus';`. I'll delete my comments if you add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for a `myclass` existance when you already have the `myclass` instance stored in a `$myclass` variable makes no sense. Maybe you should check for a method existance?

```php
if (method_exists($myclass, 'GetStatus')) {
   $fcn = function($id) use ($myclass){
      return $myclass->GetStatus($id);
   };
} else {  
   $fcn = function($id){
      return GetStatus($id);
   };
} 

echo 'result = ' . $fcn($user_id);
```